# Prevent Design Compiler from using certain cell types

Tags: physical-design, rtl

I am building an RTL design using Synopsys DC and the GTECH library that comes along with it.  It is generated using FD1, FD2, FD4 components. I would like to build the design without the FD2, FD4 components. Is there a way to prevent FD2, FD4 cells from being used when compiling the design ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, you can use the `set_dont_use` command to tell Design Compiler not to use certain library cells.